# JavaScript resize Event Detection

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I wrote the following code. it's supposed to fire when resizing the target by all possible actions. I'm working on firefox for now and it should also work cross browsers. the hick is that it does not work on firefox.

Can someone tell me why? May be I do not understand well how and when those events fire. I prefer a non-jquery solution.

```
Element.prototype.onResizeEvent = function(callBack){
    var target = this;
    target.setAttribute("data-oldHeight", target.offsetHeight); target.setAttribute("data-oldWidth", target.offsetWidth);
    var fct = function(e) {
        alert(target.getAttribute("data-oldHeight") + " " + target.offsetHeight + "\n" + target.getAttribute("data-oldWidth") + " " + target.offsetWidth);
        if (+target.getAttribute("data-oldHeight") != target.offsetHeight || +target.getAttribute("data-oldWidth") != target.offsetWidth) {
            target.setAttribute("data-oldHeight", target.offsetHeight);
            target.setAttribute("data-oldWidth", target.offsetWidth);
            callBack();
        }
    };
    try {(new MutationObserver(function() {alert(151); fct();})).observe(target, {attributes:true, childList:true, characterData:true});}
    catch(e){alert(e);}
    try {target.addEvents("DOMAttrModified propertychange", function (e) {alert(152); fct();});}
    catch(e){alert(e);}
};
```

addEvents is a custom function to handle cross browsers event attaching:

```
window.addEvents = document.addEvents = Element.prototype.addEvents = function(evNames, evFunction){
    if(!this.EventList)  this.EventList = [];
    evNames = evNames.split(" ");
    if(this.addEventListener) for(var i = 0; i < evNames.length; i++) if(evNames[i] != "") {
        this.addEventListener(evNames[i], evFunction, false);
        if(!this.EventList[evNames[i]]) this.EventList[evNames[i]] = []; this.EventList[evNames[i]].push(evFunction);
    }
    else if(this.attachEvent) for(var i = 0; i < evNames.length; i++) if(evNames[i] != ""){
        this.attachEvent("on" + evNames[i], evFunction);
        if(!this.EventList[evNames[i]]) this.EventList[evNames[i]] = []; this.EventList[evNames[i]].push(evFunction);
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Not about your problem but an important note: You should never add own functions to the prototype of elements that you don't own (except for creating poly-fills). If the specs will add the function `addEvents` or `Element.prototype.onResizeEvent`  to the standard, then this might break your code or your might break the behavior of the browser.

Comment: Thank you good point, i might rename them with more specific names like mine. though after this approach it will be hard to use any function names or variables then they might also become reserved words in the future.

Comment: You should never be adding functions to the global scope, so things being added to will not matter. You should be using a module system to load dependencies in their own scopes.

Comment: That was not why i look for here, not my question! And though again that module name might become standard too. So can someone help me with my original question please?

Comment: Another issue is: the element can resize without any DOM change, but `observer` won't trigger. Edit and check console [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r2uwmdcg/)

Comment: Ok i see. The issue here is simple, I just need all the events that I should to take in count to detect all possible cases of resizing of an element, I verify if my element's dimensions changed and call callBack if the case. Can you please tell me what are all the possible events i have to consider.